# Input data into a gridview with C#, ASP.net.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I am using a dataset that was created seperatley and is being used as a reference.

I need to create a gridview with data that comes from the dataset.

Coding is not the ASP.net code, but the C# code.

I just need to make one column of information.

Teacher has not taught us this and is on an assignment. If you can give me a link or type an example that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `"Coding is not the ASP.net code, but the C# code"` - ... What?  If this isn't ASP.NET, then what is it?  You've tagged the question with ASP.NET.  Please clarify what you're actually trying to do and, more importantly, what steps you've taken to accomplish it so far.

Comment: tried establishing connection with SQL, and tried a basic loop. But it didn't work. I am a noob lol

Comment: @JoshBarber: In general you simply assign the `DataSet` (or a `DataTable` therein) as the `.DataSource` property of the `GridView` and then call `.DataBind()` on the `GridView`.  See this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

one way to doing is to bind the required columns with empty rows to the datatable and then binding the datatable to the girdview...i have given you a sample below

```
public void GenerateColumns()
  {
   dtblDummy = new DataTable("dtblDummy");

   dtDummyColumn = new DataColumn("FirstName");
   dtblDummy.Columns.Add(dtDummyColumn);

   dtDummyColumn = new DataColumn("LastName");
   dtblDummy.Columns.Add(dtDummyColumn);

   dtDummyColumn = new DataColumn("Email");
   dtblDummy.Columns.Add(dtDummyColumn);

   dtDummyColumn = new DataColumn("Login");
   dtblDummy.Columns.Add(dtDummyColumn);

   dtDummyColumn = new DataColumn("Password");
   dtblDummy.Columns.Add(dtDummyColumn);

   dtDummyColumn = new DataColumn("Role");
   dtblDummy.Columns.Add(dtDummyColumn);

   dtDummyColumn = new DataColumn("RoleId");
   dtblDummy.Columns.Add(dtDummyColumn);   
  }

  public void GenerateRows(int intRow)
  {
   for(int intCounter = intRow; intCounter < intRow; intCounter++)
   {
    dtDummyRow = dtblDummy.NewRow();

    dtDummyRow["FirstName"] = "";
    dtDummyRow["LastName"] = "";
    dtDummyRow["Email"] = "";
    dtDummyRow["Login"] = "";
    dtblDummy.Rows.Add(dtDummyRow);
   }

   dgrdUsers.DataSource = dtblDummy;
   dgrdUsers.DataBind();

   dtblDummy = null;
   dtDummyRow = null;
   dtDummyColumn = null;
  }
```

in the above code dgrdUsers is the gridview control, and declare the dummy row, column and datatable above the page load function.

call the above two functions in your page load under ispostback....

dont forget the create the same no of columns as template column in your gridview...